# Start scroll from bottom/right xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible in xamarin ScrollView to start no from standard top or left, but from bottom or right?

```
 <ScrollView x:Name="scroll" Orientation="Horizontal">
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `ScrollToAsync(double x, double y, bool animated)` should do the trick for you. Whenever your view first appears, use that to set the scroll view to whatever position you want. Then the user will start scrolling from there.

Comment: You probably won't use it in a constructor. You might wait until the page appears for the first time, and use the dimensions of the scroll view as the `x` and `y` parameters.